# Android app does not start after renaming package in android studio

Tags: compiler-errors, android-studio, package, rename

I need to rename the package to send the app to google. But the change to org.telegram org.delai the application to start up.

It starts to load and closes.

The error I get is this:

```
06-07 05:12:24.881 21879-21879/org.delai.messenger A / libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code = 1), thread 21879 (delai.messenger)
```

I use refactor and also changed the package name in android manifest, but still the error persists.

can someone give me a light?

Thanks!.

Comment: Someone else can helpme?

Comment: i have the same problem after renaming from android studio i got this error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.telegram.SQLite.SQLitePreparedStatement" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/org.MyPackage.messenger-2.apk

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, because the package name of my app changed between different versions of my VCS (git), so whenever I checkout a version where the package name is different from the package name cached by Android Studio, the app does not start with a warning `can not find activity com.old.package.path.StartActivity`.

For me, the solution was to close and restart Android Studio so it will reload the project and reassemble the package name. After cleaning and rebuilding the project, the app starts again. It might be sufficient to go to `File` / `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in the menu of AndroidStudio

Comment: Yep, invalidate caches and restart did fix this error for my project after renaming package

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build.gradle of your project...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Set in here your application package"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```